# Sequelize - run validations if allowNull === false and the value is null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm writing an application and am using Sequelize as ORM. I've faced this problem: I have a model which has 2 fields (for simplicity, it has more actually), and they are dependant on each other, like that:

```
const Application = sequelize.define('application', {
    visa_required: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false
    },
    visa_passport_number: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: '',
        validate: {
            shouldBeSetIfVisaRequired(val) {
                if (this.visa_required && (typeof val !== 'string' || val.trim().length === 0)) {
                    throw new Error('Please fill in this field.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So if the `visa_required` field is set, the `visa_passport_number` should be also set.

Problem is, when I am passing `true` to `visa_required` and null to `visa_passport_number`, it fails with `application.visa_passport_number cannot be null` error. When I don't pass this value it goes OK (and is saved as empty string though).

I can pass `allowNull: true` as an argument for `visa_passport_number`, but that way if I'll set this value to null this validation would be ignored.

So, how can I accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those field level validations handle null strangely (IMHO).  You might want to try a row-level validation like this:

```
const Application = sequelize.define('application', {
visa_required: {
    type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: false
},
visa_passport_number: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: ''
    }
},
validate: {
    needPassportNumberIfVisaRequired() {
       if (this.visa_required && 
           (this.visa_passport_number === null
           || typeof this.visa_passport_number  !== 'string' 
           || this.visa_passport_number.trim().length === 0)) {
                throw new Error('Please fill in the passport number field.');
            }
        }
});
```